# PHP: How to pop the last item off the array without actually removing it from the array?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP get index of last inserted item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275082/php-get-index-of-last-inserted-item-in-array)

I have an array or variable length and would like a quick and easy way to know the value of the last item in the array (without actually removing it from the array). How can I pop the last item off the array without actually removing it from the array?

Comment: It wouldnt be "poping" then ;)

Answer (score 15):

Try [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

```
<?php

$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'cranberry');
echo end($fruits); // cranberry

?>
```

Comment: this works, but there is an unforeseen side effect: the array pointer is set to the end, so if you try to iterate through the array, it won't start at the beginning unless you reset it.

Comment: @Andrew: Then work on a copy or fetch by key: `$last = $array[end(array_keys($array))];` - see also the duplicates of your question.

Answer (score 3):

For numeric (non-associative) zero-based array you can use this:

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
print $arr[count($arr)-1];  // 'five'
```

Comment: and what if the array is empty?... there is no element like $arr[-1].

Comment: that only works for pure numeric arrays where no element (in the middle) is removed

Answer (score 2):

Use array end
So if I have an array:

```
$array_example = array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

And I want to get the last item, I can do it like this:

```
echo end($array_example);
```

That will echo out the last element of the array but will not effect the array.

After doing this, if you want to reset the internal array pointer to the first item in the array, (so you can continue working properly), just reset the array pointer:

```
reset($array_example);
```

Comment: it will affect the array but this works for the question which was asked here.  If you read the docs on end you see it will change the internal pointer of the array so other functions which iterate may not work as expected

Comment: True, but he just wanted the array to not be effected in the sense of not losing the last item in the array. I don't consider moving the internal pointer an effect that alters the array... so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

$lastitem = $array[count($array)-1]

this is an alternative to using end, so that you don't have the consequence of having the array's internal pointer moved to the end of the array
[end - php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

Comment: worth a downvote? just seems like one way to do it, minus the syntax error with the ) and ]

Comment: yeah, i dont know who gave you the -1. not fair in my opinion, which is why I'm giving you a +1.

Comment: made an edit to reflect the correct syntax and highlight a potential consequence of using end

Comment: Yeah this is how I normally do it so that I don't have to worry about what php is doing under the hood with internal pointers.  I guess end is more concise and easier to read though... who down voted me?

Comment: The last item in a PHP array does not necessarily have a key of count($array)-1, even when the keys are numerical, because PHP "arrays" are really linked lists.  If you say $a[1] = 'orange' and $a[0] = 'apple', then end($a) will give you 'apple' because 'apple' was added last.