# PHP function get the last inserted data in the array

Tags: php, function

I know you guys going to say this might be possible duplicate to [PHP get index of last inserted item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275082/php-get-index-of-last-inserted-item-in-array)

But I've tried and not succeed to get my function work and I'm trying to figure it out why.

I've a function which will grab the thumbnail attachment from the content of Wordpress post.

The code working fine with a post that have only one image, but if there are more than one image in the post it will display the first image correctly from the `array`, but I don't know why it stores the image in reverse. Meaning the first image of the post stored last and the last store first. I'm geussing this is maybe how the `media` function of Wordpress work.

Anyway I just need to get the last inserted data from function even if it has one or more than one image stored in the `array`

```
// Get Image Attachments
function sa_get_image($postid=0, $size='thumbnail') { 
    if ($postid<1)
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $thumb = get_post_meta($postid, "thumb", TRUE); 
    if ($thumb != null or $thumb != '') {
        echo $thumb;
    }
    elseif ($images = get_children(array( 
        'post_parent' => $postid,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => '1',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', )))
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $thumbnail=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            ?>
    <?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?> // here is the problem where the image display.
    <?php }

}
```

Comment: In your post, the word reserve was supposed to be reverse?

Comment: Damn me! Sorry I'm going to edit that now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier method to my solution and here is how we can get the last from the array.

Simply just add this to the array area.

```
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC', //If reverse use DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

change:
`$thumbnail=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);`
to:
`$thumbnail[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);`

don't forget to declarate `$thumbnail = array()` outside the for-each.

and then you can use (preferred):

`echo end($thumbnail);`

or something like:

`echo $thumbnail[count($thumbnail)-1];`

If you wan't to get the 'last' appended value.
Or you can use `[0]` or `first()` to get the first value

---

You can add it here (ex.):

```
$thumb = get_post_meta($postid, "thumb", TRUE); 
$thumbnail = array(); //<<<
if ($thumb != null or $thumb != '') {
```

Comment: Where can I declare the `$thumbnail = array()` ??

Comment: Well @Daan Timmer This is already my completed function though, as I mentioned above that without trying to get the last index it will works fine, so I'm assuming that it just some problem with the logic?

Comment: Unaccepted? You are obviously calling your function from somewhere. Thus it is not your complete code that interacts with this function/method

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried with your solution and it doesn't work. and this is the whole code I have and when I ask they said there is an array (you can look at my code) which actually control the order.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing $thumbnail as an array but you are overwriting the variable inside your foreach() as if it was a string.

Change:

```
$thumbnail=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
```

to

```
 $thumbnail[]=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
```

to make it an array then the rest of your code should work

AH

Comment: print_r() the output of wp_get_attachment_image()

Comment: I'm not really good with php is this how you do it?

`print_r ($wp_get_attachment_image() );`

Comment: Youll need to pass the values too print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size));

Comment: still I can't see anything :/