# get automatically assigned key when setting array value

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP get index of last inserted item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275082/php-get-index-of-last-inserted-item-in-array)

My array is generated the following way:

```
$_SESSION['add_fail_urls'][] = $_REQUEST['url'];
```

How do I get a number value of the automatically assigned key `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $numberOfFailedUrls = count($_SESSION['add_fail_urls']); ?>
```

Should do the trick. If you want to ensure that you don't get any notices about the `add_fail_urls` not existing, then use the following instead:

```
<?php 
    $numberOfFailedUrls = isset($_SESSION['add_fail_urls']) ? 
        count($_SESSION['add_fail_urls']) : 
        0; 
?>
```

Edit: I might've misinterpreted your post (as of @des comment), as you might want the actual index of the added element instead of the number of elements. If so, [here's a solution brought to you from @romaninsh in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10044716/860212):

```
<?php 
    end($a);
    $last_id=key($a);
?>
```