# Tree building function exceeds max execution time

Tags: php, tree, hierarchy

I'm taking around 15,000 nodes and trying to build a hierarchy from them. The nodes aren't sortable in any way, and each one can have an unlimited amount of children—but parents will always be fed to the function before their children. The code I have works for small values of N, but ends up exceeding the max execution time on the server for N>2,000. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but here's what I have:

```
function insertNode(&$treeNode, $insertNode) {
    if($insertNode['DEPTH'] <= $treeNode['DEPTH']) return false; 
    if($treeNode['ID'] == $insertNode['PARENT_ID']) {
        $treeNode['CHILDREN'][] = $insertNode;
        $treeNode['CHILD_COUNT']++;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        foreach($treeNode['CHILDREN'] as $key=>$value) {
            $found = insertNode($treeNode['CHILDREN'][$key], $insertNode);
            if($found) {
                $treeNode['CHILD_COUNT']++;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My best idea for a solution right now is limiting my recursion to building just a few thousand nodes worth of depth, and then in Javascript recalling the script for each of the bottom nodes until the tree is truly finished. I'd rather be able to have it all in one go, though.

Comment: ...wild recursion appeared!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The key was:

> parents will always be fed to the function before their children

The SQL query I was using (an Oracle `CONNECT BY`) printed out every child (and all of their children) directly after their immediate ancestors. For example, the dataset:

```
|id|parent_id|
|A-|---------|
|C-|-----A---|
|Bb|-----B---|
|B-|-----A---|
```

Would be delivered by the query as:

```
|id|parent_id|
|A-|---------|
|B-|-----A---|
|Bb|-----B---|
|C-|-----A---|
```

I was cycling through every row of the query, in order, and then calling the recursive insert function for each row. Within each function call, I was using a `foreach` loop to make a recursive call for every child of the current node in the tree until the row's parent was found, here:

```
foreach($treeNode['CHILDREN'] as $key=>$value) {
    $found = insertNode($treeNode['CHILDREN'][$key], $insertNode);
    if($found) {
        $treeNode['CHILD_COUNT']++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

But, because every child's parent was always the latest inserted item of its depth (since it was the last row I cycled through of its depth), the parent was guaranteed to be the rightmost child in the rightmost branch of the tree. Not only was the loop unnecessary, it was actually *the worst possible thing* I could have done—it was cycling through the children from left to right, but the parent was always the rightmost child of the rightmost branch, the last item the function would loop through and traverse. (What is that, `O(N^2)`?) No wonder it was timing out.

I cut the `foreach` and replaced it with an [`end()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10044716/2430028) call, instead.

```
$lastChild = $treeNode['CHILDREN'];
end($lastChild);
$key = key($lastChild);
$found = insertNode($treeNode['CHILDREN'][$key], $insertNode);
if($found) {
    $treeNode['CHILD_COUNT']++;
    return true;
}
```

This drastically shortened the execution time since it exponentially cut down how many times the function was recursively calling itself, per row. It now works for N=15,000 in about 6 seconds (before it was capping out at 30 seconds for as low as N=2,000). No node number caps or lazy loading via JS required.