# Returning array key when using array[] =

Tags: php, arrays

What is a simple method to return the array key when using array[] to add new values.

For example:

```
$array[] = 'Hello World';
return $Key_of_Hello_World;
```

The method I'm thinking of involves:

```
$key = count($array)-1;
```

Is there a different solution?

**Conclusion**

A combination of `end()` and `key()` is the best in general as it allows for associative but if your array only uses numerical keys, `count()-1` seems to be the simplest and just as fast.  I added this to the other linked question.

Comment: http://uk.php.net/manual/de/function.array-flip.php

Comment: `end($array); $key = key($array);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP get index of last inserted item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275082/php-get-index-of-last-inserted-item-in-array)

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  I must have just not searched hard enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array[] = 'Hello World';
end($array); // set internal pointer to end of array
$key = key($array); // get key of element where internal pointer is pointing at
return $key;
```

Comment: This appears to be the fastest solution, although requiring two lines of code.  Another solution suggested in the other thread was `$key = end(array_keys($array));` which is a tiny bit slower but only requires one line.  I'm still pondering whether count-1 will work well enough though as it seems just as fast as this method but obviously wouldn't work with associative like this would.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this too..

```
<?php

function printCurrKey(&$array)
{
    return array_keys($array)[count($array)-1];
}

$array[] = 'Hello World';
echo printCurrKey($array);// "prints" 0
$array[] = 'This is a new dimension !';
echo printCurrKey($array);// "prints" 1
$array['newkey'] = 'Hello World is has a new key !';
echo printCurrKey($array);// "prints" newkey
```

Comment: Yes for using the [] it seems count-1 may be the best method.  Only requires one line and is extremely fast.  array_search can be a bit slower with larger arrays but it is a interesting method. +1

Answer (score 1):

you want to use array_keys: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php

```
$array[] = 'Hello World';
return array_keys($array, 'Hello World!');
```

Comment: Came back to this after a while.  If you're looping through the array, then this is a good alternative to using end/key (since you don't want to reset the pointer).  Using something like `$keys = array_keys($array); $key = end($keys);` to avoid the strict standards warning.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/array_keys) for return keys of an array

```
return array_keys($array)
```

for individual key try to use

```
return array_keys($array, 'Hello World!');
```